# Pandas - Finding duplicates across multiple column and find the corresponding output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['cust_a','cust_b','cust_c','cust_d','cust_e','cust_a'],
'col_2':['prod_a','prod_b','prod_b','prod_a','prod_a','prod_b'],
'col_3':['cat_a','cat_b','cat_c','cat_d','cat_a','cat_a']})
```

The above returns the below Dataframe

```
col_1   col_2  col_3
cust_a  prod_a  cat_a
cust_b  prod_b  cat_b
cust_c  prod_b  cat_c
cust_d  prod_a  cat_d
cust_e  prod_a  cat_a
cust_a  prod_b  cat_a
```

I am trying to find the duplicate rows based on values in `col_1` and `col_3`.

For example, cust_a and cat_a appear twice and I am trying to filter them.

**Expected output**:

```
 col_1   col_2  col_3
cust_a  prod_a  cat_a
cust_a  prod_b  cat_a
```

I tried the below but it still has duplicates:

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `subset` in [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['col_1','col_3'], keep=False)]
print(df)
    col_1   col_2  col_3
0  cust_a  prod_a  cat_a
5  cust_a  prod_b  cat_a
```